# How do I create this link_to conditional in a DRY way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to do the following:

```
<% if current_user.has_role? :demo %>   
 <%= link_to profile_path(@selected_profile) do %>    
<% else %>    
  <%= link_to profile_path(profile) do %>    
<% end %>
```

What's throwing it off is the beginning of the block in the `link_to`, within the `if` statement.

So how do I achieve this without having to duplicate ALL of the code within this `if` block twice?

**Edit 1**

This is the error I get from the above code:

```
SyntaxError at /
syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end
'.freeze;         else 
                      ^
```

Comment: `<%= link_to something do %>
  html-code-here
<% end %>`.. you will need `end` for the `do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<% chosen_profile = current_user.has_role?(:demo) ? @selected_profile : profile %>
<%= link_to profile_path(chosen_profile) %>
```

So this will not repeat your `link_to` tag which you need to do. As you have to redirect to the same path and just change the `profile` object then this will work. You may change the ternary to if else block if the line seems very long and not readable.

And as everyone mentioned that don't use a `do` after `link_to` until you need a block. So that will fix your error.

Comment: @muistooshort Sorry which parentheses. If possible can you please correct the error if there is one.

Comment: You just found it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by defining method in you user.rb (Model)

```
  def demo?
    self.has_role?("demo")
  end
```

Then you write in your view

```
<% if current_user.demo? %>   
 <%= link_to profile_path(@selected_profile) %>    
<% else %>    
  <%= link_to profile_path(profile)  %>    
<% end %>
```

This may help you.

Comment: No you aren't understanding the issue. The issue is with the `do` within the `link_to` and the `else` within the `if`.

Comment: Your suggestion will give me the same error I am getting now.

Comment: remove do clause from link_to  tag. I edited my answer

Comment: lol...bro...I need it! What follows after that is the entire contents of the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

`do` should have `end`.

1. Here is the [Ruby Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) reference for link_to
2. Here is more about [`do` in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Tutorial/part_02/loops.html)

   ```
   <% if current_user.has_role? :demo %>   
    <%= link_to profile_path(@selected_profile) do %> 
      selected profile
    <% end %>   
   <% else %>    
     <%= link_to profile_path(profile) do %> 
      profile  
     <% end %>  
   <% end %>
   ```

Comment: Yeh I was trying to not have duplicated code...but I take your point.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of `do`, you are opening the block but not closing it, try this code

```
<% if current_user.has_role? :demo %>   
 <%= link_to 'Profile', profile_path(@selected_profile) %>    
<% else %>    
  <%= link_to 'Profile', profile_path(profile) %>    
<% end %>
```

**or**, you can do it in controller instead

```
@selected_profile = current_user.has_role?(:demo) ? @selected_profile : profile
```

and then in the view,

```
<%= link_to 'Profile', profile_path(@selected_profile) %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The top part doesn't work, but the bottom suggestion kinda does. I still need the `do` in the `link_to`.